# ASINetworkQueue Correct Usage and Storage

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, nsoperationqueue, reachability

I have an app that submits data using ASIFormDataRequest to a remote web site. I want to allow the user to store them for upload later if they are offline (eg: iPod touch or out of cell coverage, etc). Is ASINetworkQueue the appropriate tool to use? I imagine I would store the request in a queue belonging to the app delegate and, whenever a new submission was added or the app launched, reachability would be tested and, if good, would complete each request in the queue.

Is that logic correct? (I know it is bad practice to check reachability immediately on app launch, but I would tweak that to a good time.)

If so, my next question is, how do I get a ASINetworkQueue to persist between launches, both cold and from background? I imagine it would involve writing it to NSData and writing that to NSUserDefaults or even to file.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to upload data asynchronously but handle offline usage, I would recommend writing the data to a local database or file and then having some sort of "uploaded at" timestamp for a status.  When your app starts up you can query your local database for any objects that have not been uploaded.  I don't know what your app is doing but you may find this method less error prone and better for giving proper feedback to your user through the UI.